# Method for greater than one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a query that I run in Rails:

```
me = User.find(1)
my_groups = me.groups
```

`my_groups` can return more than one row, potentially.

Is there a quick and dirty way to use a method to determine if `my_groups` or `me.groups` is greater than one?

Maybe something like `my_groups.greater_than_one?`  If not, what would you recommend in determining if the query is return >1 row?

`me.groups` is essentially another table that is associated with User.  It basically shows what "groups" a particular user belongs to.

Comment: What is `me.groups`? A collection (e.g. ActiveRecord::Relation)? A number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There needn’t be a method for everything, you can simply compare against `size`:

```
me.groups.size > 1
```

However, [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) does have [`many?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-many-3F) which will return `true` if there is more than one record. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-many-3F):

> Returns `true` if the collection has more than one record. Equivalent to
>   `collection.size > 1`.
>
> ```
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :pets
> end
>
> person.pets.count #=> 1
> person.pets.many? #=> false
>
> person.pets << Pet.new(name: 'Snoopy')
> person.pets.count #=> 2
> person.pets.many? #=> true
> ```

If you only cared about if there are *any* elements (i.e. >0) there’s [`any`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-any-3F) (which is also part of [Ruby core’s Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)). But beware `[nil, false].any? #=> false`.

Comment: Thanks Marshall!  I like `many?` -- that's exactly what I was looking for.  Also, a good reminder on using `size` as well.

Comment: @Dodinas Comparing `size` is what you would do if you didn’t have ActiveSupport (since `many?` is not in Ruby core).

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by:

```
if me.groups.count > 1 # or me.groups.size > 1 or me.groups.any?
 'bla bla...'
else
  ....
end
```

But I do recommend to have [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) in User class.

To do so:

1. Add a column `groups_count` to `users` table

   `add_column :users, :groups_count, :integer, default: 0`
2. In Group model

   `belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true`

Thus you can achieve your goal by:

```
if me.groups_count > 1
 'bla bla...'
else
  ....
end
```

This will reduce the db query